# Advice for Australian with dual citizenship (US/Australia) married to a US citizen and they move to Australia

Tags: usa, australia

If both myself (dual citizen usa/australia) and my husband (us citizen) are living in Australia and we each make over $150,000USD per year - are we really in a bad spot with US taxes and getting double taxed since we make quite a bit more than the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion (FEIE) allows for?

Comment: This is unanswerable, as whether you're in a "bad spot" is a matter of opinion. As US citizens, both of you must file US income tax returns. Your 1040s will tell you whether or how much of the FEIE can be applied. Given your salaries, even if the FEIE can be applied twice, you'll owe US taxes.

Comment: You might get a more detailed answer at [Money.SE].  The FEIE isn't the only consideration, of course.  There's also the foreign tax deduction and possibly a tax treaty.

Comment: Thank you David and Phoog!